# url renaming dynamically in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am developing a website  in which all members have a provision to set their own url.

For example, my site address is `www.example.com`.

if a member set his url as `www.example.com/his_name`, This url is stored in database along with the user id.

When this user enter this url he should get his page.

In my site a common page called `profile?id=$id`, which displays each person's profile.
So when  user enter `www.example.com/his_name` , will display his page..

But there is no page named `'his_name'`.

How can I achive this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google for `mod_rewrite` and related

Comment: You should search for `.htaccess mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

In your `profile.php` code, you will have to handle the username in `$_GET['id']` and then display the appropriate webpage.

You should search for `mod_rewrite` for more information about this topic.